# Can not create inheritor of build-in loopback user model. Just returns empty object in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs

This is code of creating new user. But it does not work. In loopaback explorer everything works fine.

```
 Participant.create({
        email: `${body.login}@yandex.by`,
        password: '1111',
      }, function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);//undefined
```

This code also does not work.

```
 request.post('http://localhost:3000/api/Participants', {
        form: {
          email: `${body.login}@yandex.by`,
          password: '1111',
        },
      }, function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);//undefined
```

Comment: Please provide your model in loopback

Comment: what is your error message?

Comment: Hi,@аlexdykyі https://github.com/KirylLapouski/testManager/blob/master/test-manager-api/common/models/participant.json

Comment: Hi, @icecream_hobbit There is no error message, just empty model in callback.